# Postgres xml data type in a frequently updating data set

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, rss

I’m working on an RSS reader that will store information from an RSS feed into a `feed` table. I would like to re-fetch the RSS feeds every 15 minutes (respecting ETags and other HTTP cache headers) to detect any updates. I’m expecting about 30,000 RSS feeds each with about 100 items.

Is it reasonable to use the Postgres `xml` data type for this large and frequently updating data set? Or should I parse out relevant fields in my code that fetches the feeds and store them in individual columns in the Postgres table?

In SQL:

```
create table channel (
  id serial primary key,
  xml xml
);
```

vs.

```
create table channel (
  id serial primary key,
  title text,
  link text,
  description text,
  -- etc.
);
```

The RSS feed won’t be changing every 15 minutes, I just want to check frequently to be sure to catch any updates. Because of this `suppress_redundant_updates_trigger` seems like a good choice, but I am not sure if it will work with the `xml` data type because there is no way to check equality between `xml` types in Postgres. Would it make sense to convert the `xml` to text and check equality that way?

I would prefer to use the `xml` type because it means I don’t have to predict the contents of the RSS feed. I can get everything and dynamically derive the information I need using `xpath`. Would it be a bad idea to use the `xml` type in a frequently updating large data set?

Comment: If you want to use `suppress_redundant_updates_trigger` to gain speed, [don't do that](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-trigger.html): The *normal behavior* (without this trigger) *makes updates run faster, since no checking is required, and is also useful in certain cases.* -- If you want to use the trigger to minimize [dead tuples](https://www.google.hu/search?q=postgresql+table+fragmentation): don't do that either. Large `xml` values will be [TOASTed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html) anyway.

Comment: I don't expect the `xml` values to be incredibly big, perhaps about 10–15 elements in each with smallish text content values. Would they be TOASTed?

Comment: 10-15 elements means nothing to me (and nothing to PostgreSQL either). It's size in bytes what matters.

Comment: For comparison, [SO's postgresql tag's feed](http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/+or+postgresql) is around 84kB at the moment. I would say that would be TOASTed f.ex.

Comment: The text I want to store is about 2kB per row in some of my example data sets (individual RSS items go in their own rows). Update speed isn’t a problem for me, but it seems like dead rows and frequent index updates could be.

Comment: you want to fine tune the [`fillfactor` storage parameter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-STORAGE-PARAMETERS) then. And possibly [autovacuum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-autovacuum.html). -- `fillfactor` with [HOT updates](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/2e78013d0611141101m6110d275o93304e7ca31be851@mail.gmail.com) will take care of your problem (but will cost you some disk space)...

Comment: ... But I'm no expert on tuning those. You may want to ask a specific question about it. Possibly on [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: What about serializing the XML to a string and comparing that in the code where I am about to update the table as a more specific redundant update suppresser?

Comment: It would make updates even more slower (even slower than with `suppress_redundant_updates_trigger`). And a single whitespace difference would make a new physical row, still. You'll need to decide what is more important to you.

Comment: My other tradeoff is to normalize everything. Do you want to write about the tradeoffs and links as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: then I may misinterpreted your question. If by normalization, you mean your second table format, that's no better than the first in almost any circumstances. I doubt that your xml is large(ish), because of the meta-data (attribute & tag names), but because of attribute (and text) values. And if you can work better with the single xml format, there is really no question at all (so I didn't think of it as an option at all).

Comment: so here is my question: store as raw xml or store in normalized database form with title, description separately?